# "rsh" timesout when "-n" option used

Tags: timeout, rsh

I am issuing a "rsh" command from a batch file (.bat). The "rsh" command has an option "-n". The command that gets executed on the remote machine takes around 10 mins to complete.

I noticed that the rsh ***times out and terminates*** in about 2 mins (causing other problems) if "-n" option is used however it ***doesn't timeout*** and the remote command completes successfully *if "-n" option is **not** used*.

Can anyone explain this behavior as to why "rsh" is timing out when "-n" option is used from DOS?

What could be the problems if I don't use "-n" option in my "rsh" command?